# Dynamic Lighting in (vanilla) Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have already seen tutorials on Minecraft regarding dynamic lighting, but none of them seem fancy enough.

What I'm thinking of is a way to make dynamic lighting that is clean and not destructive.

I looked at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Elsa7wx2fi0), and some other videos do the trick mentioned as well, but as pointed out in [this one here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhrIvpORRfE&t=128s), using a block that emits light overhead has its disadvantages, mainly due to other blocks interfering with the light source.

There are also ones with the blindness/night-vision combo, but they nowadays produce pitch blackness (which is where I am not intending to go to.).

As stated in the title, I am trying to do this without the following:

- Mods/Shaders
- Resource Packs*

Is there any way to do this while avoiding the above and if also, something relatively small?

**NOTE:** As stated by @Fabian, resource packs are vanilla, but I'm trying to do this with the default pack.

Comment: Interesting that you put mods and shaders into different categories, but shaders and resource packs into one category. Resource packs are Vanilla, the rest is modded.

Comment: Can I ask why? Not to be offensive or critical, but I'm wondering specifically what you want to do, because some possible solutions work in very specific circumstances. I've been working on this in my head for a while, and I'm glad I'm not the only one that wants it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a torch that, when held, gives you night vision (sans-blindness). However, this would mean that everything you see will be lit up, which might not be ideal for your use-case.

Alternatively, you could use Cimap's method and make it so that when the end portal block disappears (due to the player being too close to a ceiling) it gives the player night vision to make up for the loss of light.

Comment: This is a great answer! My question was mainly just out of curiosity, but this looks like a good thing to build upon. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Building on The Nameless Steve's first option, I figured out a way to make some (rudimentary) kind of dynamic lighting, although I think it may only work in 1.12 and up due to a glitch that occurs when the following is done in some previous versions.

1. Give yourself Night Vision.
2. Give yourself Blindness.

*Note: as pointed out above, if this is performed in previous versions, it will glitch and black out your field of vision.

If successful, it should make a (reduced) field of vision (probably more fitting in pitch black areas), but the field has a light level of 15.