# (Java Minecraft 1.14) How to make a non-block light source without mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As the title says, I would like to make a light source that I can summon into the world without using `setblock` or optifine's dynamic lights option. I tried using the minecraft:flash particle, the minecraft:end_rod particle, the minecraft:lava and minecraft:falling_lava particles, the redstone dust particle, and the minecraft:flame particle, but they don't actually produce any light. The particle minecraft:dripping_lava glows so it can actually be seen in a cave, but it doesn't actually illuminate anything.

Are there any ways, including resource packs, datapacks, particles, invisible armor stands, really anything besides physical blocks that can make a light source? I'm fine if the block is being held or worn by an entity, but I don't want to give anyone night vision or blindness.

Bonus points if that light source can be teleported/moved around with a player, and if you know what the minecraft:flash particle actually does ingame.

If this is absolutely impossible, where can I make a suggestion for it?

Finally, I have seen [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212650/minecraft-creating-light-without-a-source-block) question and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316221/dynamic-lighting-in-vanilla-minecraft) question, but  they are now pretty old, as well as neither of them having any answers that suit my situation.

**Edit:** And until someone figures out some hack to make this work, vote for [this](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360048059532-Add-a-particle-that-is-a-light-source-) suggestion to add a particle that actually emits light.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this into a command block and set to needs redstone

```
/summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~1.49 ~ {NoGravity:1,Time:0,BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:emerald_block"}}
```

then place a glowstone block above the command block and a barrier above that and activate the command block. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but this is the best I could find.

this works in 1.13 and I couldn't find anything for 1.14 so I'd assume it's the same command.

Comment: But that doesn't create a light source, does it? It just summons a falling emerald block in the player's head that disappears instantly. I tried changing it to glowstone but the glowstone block doesn't actually produce any light.

Comment: Sorry I left out some important info. Try it now. @Nik3141

Comment: Thanks @Robbie but I'm trying to create something that requires no actual physical blocks and is soft-coded, as in I'm not trying to create hidden lighting for a specific place but hidden lighting that moves with the player/can be created in any circumstance without affecting terrain. I'm trying to create something super flexible but I think it's just not possible right now.

Comment: What about invisible creative lighting blocks?